# Upload image with Angular to Django Rest Framework encoding error

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for the first time and I'm trying to upload an image through Angular 8.

I am able to upload an image through postman without any problem, but when I make a post request with Angular I get the following error message: `JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 153: invalid start byte`.

I have tried adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form tag, but that did not seem to make any difference.

If there a simple solution I'm not seeing here?

**models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
  photo = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.photo.title
```

**photo.service.ts**

```
upload(formData): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(
    `${this.apiUrl}/upload/`,
    formData,
    this.httpOptions
  );
}
```

**add-photo.component.ts**

```
handleSelectPhoto(event) {
  if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
    const photo = event.target.files[0];
    this.photoForm.get("photo").setValue(photo);
  }
}

handleSubmit(title) {
  const photoFile = this.photoForm.get("photo").value;
  if (!photoFile) {
    return;
  }

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("photo", photoFile);
  this.photoService.upload(formData).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

**views.py**

```
class FileUploadParser(APIView):
  parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)

    if file_serializer.is_valid():
      file_serializer.save()
      return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
      return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: add your `view`

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta, I have added my view. I am using FileUploadParser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using `JSONParser` instead a file `MultiPartParser`, `FileUploadParser`, etc.

See an example below

```
class FileUploadView(CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
```

Referencne: https://learnbatta.com/blog/parsers-in-django-rest-framework-85/